# Problems with react native node_modules and sending it forward to other devs

Tags: react-native, version-control, node-modules

"I've had to make changes to **node_modules** so I would be able to build with:

```
npx expo run:android
```

My question is, while I'm alone hands-on this project, it's all good because nobody touches the project besides me.

Now I'm at a point where others are going to start developing this project, and I don't want to run them through the process of fixing their problematic node_modules build.gradle files to set the correct version for everything to work.

Is there any way to fix it and remove these types of conflicts?
Where is the base of all these types of problems generally?"